# What is a scale consisting of Root, m2, m3, P4, d5, M6, M7 called?

Tags: scales

Root, m2, m3, P4, d5, M6, M7

G, A flat, B flat,  C, D flat,  E, F#

Comment: Closest I could find was G dorian b2 or "Javanese scale".. not sure if the F# fits though. Its the second mode of the melodic minor. http://www.scales-chords.com/fscale_res_en.php?rn1=G&rn2=G%23%2FAb&rn3=A%23%2FBb&rn4=C&rn5=C%23%2FDb&rn6=E&rn7=F%23%2FGb&rn8=&rn9=&normal=1&greek=1&greekalt=1&other=1&etnic=1&c1=&t1=&c2=&t2=&c3=&t3=

Answer (score 5):

You can ask [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com) to identify scales for you.

[When we ask it about your scale](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=music+scale+g+a+flat+b+flat+c+d+flat+e+f+sharp), it tells us that the scale is an F harmonic Neapolitan minor scale. Unfortunately, it doesn't suggest any scales centered around G (except the chromatic scale, but that contains every note).

Comment: I doubt it can be an F harmonic Neapolitan minor scale if the scale doesn't even contain an F! (Maybe the OP changed the question in the meantime ...)

Comment: No, you're right. I think WolframAlpha counts all scales that contain the requested notes, even if they include other notes.

Comment: But even then it's doesn't work out because F Neapolitan minor has no G. I guess WolframAlpha is better at math than at music ... :)

Comment: WolframAlpha can handle quite a few queries about music. Here's a list of examples: http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Music.html

Answer (score 3):

The closest scale I've found was the [Neapolitan Major Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_scale), but the fifth is perfect instead of diminished. There is a possibility that this scale is unnamed because this combination does not come up too much in music. If you really wanted, you could probably call that scale **Neapolitan Major b5** since it is only one note off.

Comment: Wound't it be a Neapolitan minor scale, since the 3rd is flat? And could we make it a Neapolitan harmonic minor, since the 7th is raised?

Comment: @Kevin No since the Major Neapolitan scale has `root, m2, m3, P4, P5, M6, M7` and the Minor has `root, m2, m3, P4, P5, m6, M7`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it has a name, but from the aug 2nd between Db and E, it clearly isn't a diatonic scale. However, the m2 and dim5 do suggest a similarity to the Locrian Mode. In fact, the only difference to the Locrian mode is the raised 6th and 7th scale degrees. This is similar to the raised 6th and 7th scale degrees in the (ascending) melodic minor, so perhaps this is some form of **Melodic Locrian** scale? (And yes, that is quite the oxymoron).

Googling for that term, I found [this list](https://gist.github.com/lfnoise/bcf1f3e8713c1dd1d6e8) of heptatonic (7-note) scales. Using it's interval-based notation, your scale translates as "013569E" (T and E stand for Ten and Eleven, respectively), which it indeed lists as a Melodic Locrian.

DISCLAIMER: That page says that it uses an algorithm to assign names to scales where needed:

> an algorithm attempts to give a name for each viable mode.

so this may not be a standard terminology.

EDIT: Your scale also shows up on [this huge list](http://psg.com/~dlamkins/lamkins-guitar/Tools/scales.html) of heptatonic scales, at position #132. It isn't given a name. Given that this scale doesn't seem to have a proper name, I think either Locrian #6 #7 or Dom's suggested Neapolitan Major b5 would be an adequate description.